# How to handle colored output from command in perl?

Tags: perl, colors, terminal

I need to execute command from Perl script and print it's output, however command output is colored and Perl prints something like that:

```
ESC[33m sample text ESC[m
```

instead of coloring `sample text`.

In other words: I want to know how to handle already colored input in Perl (not how to create colored output)

Comment: Chances are good that you can convince the other program not to output color data at all by setting `$ENV{TERM}` to something basic like `vt100`.

Comment: And if `vt100` does not work, then try `dumb`.

Answer (score 9):

I would start with the `colorstrip` function in [Term::ANSIColor](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html)

Answer (score 4):

[uncolor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?uncolor)

> uncolor takes input from files or standard input and returns in with
>   colors and attributes stripped.